# Debian 11 doesn't see Disk

Tags: debian, partition, dual-boot, hard-disk, debian-installer

At wit's end, I am working with:

debian-11.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso, and
Dell Latitude 7390 with Win10 Pro

Installer does not see the laptop's disk

I have tried:

1. Standard procedure for installer to partition
2. Pre-preparing partitions with W10
3. Turning off Secure boot
4. Change from default RAID to AHCI, W10 won't boot (SATA not selectable in this BIOS)
5. Adding dmraid=true to kernel command line.

I don't know what else to do.

I have read poetry about Microsoft dinking with BIOS settings to prevent installs of other OS's but I am skeptical.

I do see that the storage options include both SATA and mPCIE, the BIOS seems to indicate the presence of both.

Does anyone know what I can do? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I barked up that RST tree for a while, but my version of W10, (very recent) didn't map to the help I found. The trick of it turned out to be getting W10 to boot into AHCI mode. I found this here that provided an easy path (CMD):

[Switch RAID to AHCI without reinstalling Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1359471/402107)

Once Windows was booting, Deb11 went right in.

Answer (score 2):

As expected with modern laptops, the "disk" is actually a SSD. [The hardware vendor's SSD replacement documentation](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/latitude-13-7390-laptop_install-guide2_en-us.pdf) identifies its physical form as a M.2 2230 SSD.

It is probably a NVMe SSD, so it will require that the `nvme` module is loaded, and will show up as `/dev/nvme0n1`, not as `/dev/sda`. You might want to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch from the installer into a root shell prompt to investigate further.

Whether the driver recognizes the SSD or not, you should see it in a `lspci -nn` listing if it is a NVMe SSD. If it has a strange OEM vendor/product ID, the `nvme` module might not recognize it automatically. The `lspci -nn` will show the IDs in the form `[vendor:product]`. Once you know the hexadecimal IDs, you will be able to force the module to recognize the device with `echo "vendor product" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/new_id`.

For example, if `lspci -nn` indicates that the IDs are `[12ab:34cd]`, then you could run:

```
echo "12ab 34cd" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/new_id
```

If this allows the device to be detected and the installation to proceed, you'll want to create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/nvme.conf` with the contents like:

```
install nvme /sbin/modprobe -i nvme; /bin/echo "12ab 34cd" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/new_id
```

to automate the ID addition process. This file needs to be included into initramfs, so you would have to run `update-initramfs -u -k all` after editing it.

You might also want to report the ID to the Linux NVMe subsystem development mailing list: linux-nvme@lists.infradead.org, so that future kernel versions will be able to auto-detect the ID without this process.

Comment: Thank you @telcoM. Didn't see your answer until after I fixed it, sorry. Folks are fast around here, and that's great! I hope I can help someone here soon.

Comment: Since switching to AHCI mode helped, it looks like my guess was wrong anyway. Welp, hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to disable "VMD" in my UEFI/"BIOS".

> The Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) driver version 18.0 and later support Intel® Volume Management Device (Intel® VMD) technology capable platforms. Intel® VMD is the new way to configure 11th Generation and greater Intel® Core™ Processor-based platforms for Intel® RST management of RAID and Intel® Optane™ memory volumes.
>
> ...
>
> The Intel RST driver does not support Linux.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057787/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html

After doing so my Windows partition failed to boot (expected) but the Debian live USB can now see my disk! "Hopefully" Windows will boot after I re-enable VMD. edit: yep, Windows boots again after re-enabling VMD in UEFI.